Preposition after 'responsibility'
In my exam, I was asked to find grammatical error in the following sentence:
"The students refused to accept responsibility for their acts."
And according to answer, it should be 'of' in place of 'for'.
But I have seen many sentences with 'for' after responsibility. Why is it error here then?

It's a rubbish exam. It's almost always for in the cited context.

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a very poor quality "exam" question

The ignorant test-setter is probably getting confused by contexts like Maintaining grass verges in residential roads is the responsibility of the local council.

The exam is wrong. There doesn't seem to be any error in the given sentence.
"Accept responsibility" usually pairs with "for." There are other usages that take other words: If we want to link the "responsibility" with a person, we say "that's the responsibility of that person." And we say "that person has a responsibility to do that." But we say "they accept responsibility for their acts."
If you have the option, I suggest learning from a different source.

I think has a responsibility to do that  is an infinitive marker, but if they delegate responsibility to someone else, that's another preposition. And you could be responsible under the law for doing something, or responsible within certain limits. There are a lot of possible prepositions for adverbial modifiers.

This answer is correct so I see no need to belabor the point.

@Andy Bonner the "to" in "... responsibility to do that" is not a preposition but a subordinator. Its function is that of special marker for VPs of infinitival clauses.
